# Dead-simple web authentication for a single user

Tags: python, security, authentication, web-applications

I wrote a small internal web app using (a subset of) [pylons](http://pylonshq.com/). As it turns out, I now need to allow a user to access it from the web. This is not an application that was written to be web facing, and it has a bunch of gaping security holes.

What is the simplest way I can make sure this site is securely available to that user, but no one else?

I'm thinking something like apache's simple HTTP authentication, but more secure. (Is OpenID a good match?)

There is only one user. No need for any user management, not even to change password. Also, I trust the user not to damage the server (it's actually his).

If it was for me, I would just keep it behind the firewall and use ssh port forwarding, but I would like to have something simpler for this user.

**EDIT**: Hmm... judging by the answers, this should have been on serverfault. If a moderator is reading this, consider migrating it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if there's only a single user, [using a certificate](http://impetus.us/~rjmooney/projects/misc/clientcertauth.html) would probably be easiest.

Comment: certificates are more reliable than ip address, go with this one.

Comment: That looks good. Got a similar page for Ubuntu, by any chance?

Comment: Google found that one for me.  I'm sure it can work the same magic for you.  :-)

Comment: Apparently I needed to look no further than /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl under ubuntu 9.04...

Answer (score 4):

How about VPN? There should be plenty of user-friendly VPN clients. He might already be familiar with the technology since many corporations use them to grant workers access to internal network while on the road.

Answer (score 2):

Basic HTTP authentication can be bruteforced easily by tools like brutus. If his ip is static you can allow his ip and deny all others with htaccess.

Comment: Use HTTP Digest, it's considerably more secure.

Comment: HTTP Digest is only better than Basic HTTP Auth because the password isn't transmitted plaintext but both can easily be bruteforced.

Comment: The wikipedia article also states that it's encrypted data transfer is exploitable by rainbow tables, which means there's not a whole lot of difference between Basic Auth and Digest. Digest is just harder to break initially. Both forms offer a false sense of security.

Comment: Only you have the patience, rainbow tables, and the server doesn't handle the nonces well.  Watching the IP addresses requesting nonces makes it very difficult to brute force; the server can count requesting addresses over a short period of time and refuse to cooperate with any address over some limit.

Comment: Sniff the network, steal the transmission. Rainbow tables can crack it in a few minutes if it's not a complex password, hours if it is. Then you have the password without ever once attempting to log into the server.